# passing quoted arguments to node via shell script?

Tags: bash, node.js

I have a text file where each line is a list of arguments I want to pass to a nodejs script. Here's an example file, file.txt:

```
"This is the first argument" "This is the second argument"
```

For demonstration's sake, the node script is simply:

```
console.log(process.argv.slice(2));
```

I want to run this node script for every line in the text file, so I made this bash script, run.sh:

```
while read line; do
    node script.js $line
done < file.txt
```

When I run this bash script, this is what I get:

```
$ ./run.sh 
[ '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'first',
  'argument"',
  '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'second',
  'argument"' ]
```

But when I just run the node script directly I get the expected output:

```
$ node script.js "This is the first argument" "This is the second argument"
[ 'This is the first argument',
  'This is the second argument' ]
```

What's going on here? Is there a more node-ish way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's going on here is that `$line` isn't getting sent to your program in the way you expect.  If you add the `-x` flag at the beginning of your script (like `#!/bin/bash -x`, for example), you can see every line as it's being interpreted before it gets executed.  For your script, the output looks like this:

```
$ ./run.sh 
+ read line
+ node script.js '"This' is the first 'argument"' '"This' is the second 'argument"'
[ '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'first',
  'argument"',
  '"This',
  'is',
  'the',
  'second',
  'argument"' ]
+ read line
```

See all those single-quotes?  They're definitely not where you want them to be.  You can use `eval` to get everything quoted correctly.  This script:

```
while read line; do
    eval node script.js $line
done < file.txt
```

Gives me the correct output:

```
$ ./run.sh 
[ 'This is the first argument', 'This is the second argument' ]
```

Here's the `-x` output too, for comparison:

```
$ ./run.sh 
+ read line
+ eval node script.js '"This' is the first 'argument"' '"This' is the second 'argument"'
++ node script.js 'This is the first argument' 'This is the second argument'
[ 'This is the first argument', 'This is the second argument' ]
+ read line
```

You can see that in this case, after the `eval` step, the quotes are in the places you want them to be.  Here's the documentation on `eval` from the [`bash(1)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> **eval** [*arg* ...]
>
> The *args* are read and concatenated together into a single command. This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of **eval**. If there are no *args*, or only null arguments, **eval** returns 0.